# Sharing views between Rails 3 applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering what you think of the several methods there are to accomplish this:

1. Use symlinks for the shared files
2. Create a gem/plugin that provides the shared files and code
3. Create a web service that pulls views/partials from the required app and stores it in a cache

My objective is to reduce complexity in a large application. Let's say I want to build an online community, and I want one app to handle forums, another to handle user galleries, etc., and a central one which manages users and provides common views to the other apps.

So, the master application would have to provide a common layout and widgets to all others, and each app would need to provide some views to the master app too.

For example, say the layout has a main menu with an item for each app, and each item has an over-sized sub-menu, so I can't just have a simple list of label and URL pairs.

So perhaps the master app would ask each child app to provide its menu item and contents through a private API, build the menu, save the output in a cache, and send the full menu to each app when asked.

As you can see, I'm already leaning towards option 3, but I wanted some feedback on my approach and if maybe there's a better way.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe it really sounds like you should be using a single Rails application.  The view interdependency makes me think that you might benefit from this approach.  I also imagine that testing will be more difficult because your 'application' will span three actual Rails applications.

That said, if you are set on using three applications, I would recommend against using and API.  APIs are great for passing data (json, xml...) back and forth, but they aren't as well suited to views.  My recommendation would be to create a plugin of common views that could be stored in a separate git repository and simply used within each of your applications.  That way the common code is shared amongst the applications yet still locally accessible to all of them.

Comment: My app is much more complex, I just used that as an example :) The more I think about it do, I realize you're right, I'm better off with a plugin, because a web service entails a lot more complexity, like I'd have to cache both in the master and children apps in case any one of them goes down.

Comment: I've been reading about engines in Rails 3, and it seems they're perfect for what I want. Here's some useful info: http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/05/rails-3-plugins---part-2---writing-an-engine/

Comment: That looks like a great place to start.